# Trying to create a polygon type button using matrial-UI and React

Tags: css, reactjs, button, material-ui

[image]

above poly button am trying to create, this is a just design. I tried different method to style it. anyone has any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing (IMO) would be to define a CSS [`clipPath`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) for your polygon in your [Button](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-button/)'s [`sx`](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/button/#props) prop -- *or* create a [styled component](https://mui.com/system/styled/) (`button`), in which you can define your CSS [`clipPath`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path), then pass that styled component to the `Button`'s [`component` prop](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/button/#props).

**Example (via `styled` component):**

In my example, I just used a basic star since I didn't have your polygon to work with.

```
const StarButton = styled("button")({
  width: "300px",
  height: "300px",
  background: "linear-gradient(red, orange)",
  clipPath:
    "polygon(50% 2.4%, 34.5% 33.8%, 0% 38.8%, 25% 63.1%, 19.1% 97.6%, 50% 81.3%, 80.9% 97.6%, 75% 63.1%, 100% 38.8%, 65.5% 33.8%)",
  shapeOutside:
    "polygon(50% 2.4%, 34.5% 33.8%, 0% 38.8%, 25% 63.1%, 19.1% 97.6%, 50% 81.3%, 80.9% 97.6%, 75% 63.1%, 100% 38.8%, 65.5% 33.8%)"
});

const MyStarButtonComponent = () => {
  return (
      <Button
        component={StarButton}
        variant="contained"
      >
        MUI Button
      </Button>
  )
}
```

Which would effectively produce a button with the appearance of a polygon:

[image: example star button]

**Example (via `sx` prop):**

```
<Button
  variant="contained"
  sx={{
    width: "300px",
    height: "300px",
    background: "linear-gradient(red, orange)",
    clipPath: "polygon(50% 2.4%, 34.5% 33.8%, 0% 38.8%, 25% 63.1%, 19.1% 97.6%, 50% 81.3%, 80.9% 97.6%, 75% 63.1%, 100% 38.8%, 65.5% 33.8%)",
    shapeOutside: "polygon(50% 2.4%, 34.5% 33.8%, 0% 38.8%, 25% 63.1%, 19.1% 97.6%, 50% 81.3%, 80.9% 97.6%, 75% 63.1%, 100% 38.8%, 65.5% 33.8%)"
  }}
>
  MUI Button via sx
</Button>
```

**Extra credit:** Also in my example, I added [`shapeOutside`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside) so other items on the page can flow around the button *(totally not required though)*:

[image: example star button with text]

**Working CodeSandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-sid-hvsx84?file=/demo.tsx

---

***Note:*** You can also define your `clipPath` via a hidden `SVG` element in the page and then refer to it in your CSS by `id` (so you don't have to convert your points for the `clipPath`), but with this you lose the ability to define the `shapeOutside` and have it "behave" more like a polygon.

```
<svg
  style={{
    position: "absolute",
    width: 0,
    height: 0
  }}
 >
  <clipPath id="my-clip-path" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <path d="M0.5,0,0.638,0.354,1,0.382,0.723,0.629,0.809,1,0.5,0.799,0.191,1,0.277,0.629,0,0.382,0.362,0.354,0.5,0"></path>
  </clipPath>
</svg>

<Button
  variant="contained"
  sx={{ clipPath: "url(#my-clip-path)" }}
>
  MUI Button via sx/SVG
</Button>
```

[image: example using SVG as a clip-path]

Comment: is the any web page to create custom clipPath for creating polygons?

Comment: @shafavp Directions for that depend on the graphics [SVG] editor you're using (Illustrator, Figma, etc.), or you could see if you have any luck with something like this: https://yoksel.github.io/relative-clip-path/

Comment: thank you very much, and last question,  is there any way to add border radius , hover-bg color for ploygon star ?

Comment: @shafavp I've updated the CodeSandbox with a background change on hover (styled component example) -- border radius won't have an effect because of the poly shape with this solution, but you can add a border in your directly in your clipPath (if I understand the use case correctly).